# Асинхронный вызов exec работает под root, но не работает под www-data

Tags: php

Написал скрипт, который генерирует снапшоты страниц, если к ней обратился бот и её срок годности истёк. Чтобы избежать ситуации, когда бот каждый раз ждёт по 2-3 секунды, пока headless-chrome закончит обработку страницы, я пытаюсь сделать снапшот в фоне, чтобы робот получил уже существующую версию снапшота за ~100мс и был доволен моим TTFB. А при следующем обращении он уже получит свежую версию. Но мой код не работает, если вызов функции происходит от имени пользователя **www-data**. Проверил это при помощи запуска этой же команды от рута и скрипт прекрасно отработал. Как можно решить эту проблему? Есть ли в php асинхронные функции?

Код вызова асинхронного php-скрипта:

```
exec('php snapshot.php -l ' . urlencode($full_uri) . ' &> /dev/null &');
```

Код **snapshots.php**:

```
require 'functions.php';

$options = getopt('l:');
$url = urldecode($options['l']);

$html = getSnapshotHTML($url);
$source_code = pg_escape_string($html['source_code']);

$postgre = new Postgre();
$connect = $postgre->connect();
$url_path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$now = time();

if($html['status_code'] == 200) {
    $query = "UPDATE snapshots SET (html, inserted) = ('{$source_code}', '{$now}') WHERE pathname = '{$url_path}'";
    $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
}

pg_close($connect);
```

Comment: Кто владелец скриптов и папок? [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538939/php-exec-will-not-execute-shell-command-when-executed-via-browser) есть похожая проблема.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107339/parallel-processing-in-php-how-do-you-do-it

Comment: @Rootwate выставил файлу snapshot.php владельца www-data - не помогло.

Comment: Проверьте также и группу. Обычно для работы php-fpm используется та же группа - www-data. Также проверьте что этот пользователь может запускать php через exec('php -i')

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно случайно напоролся на чей-то ответ на англоязычном StackOverflow, где рекомендовалось посылать команду с абсолютными путями. То есть, вместо:

```
exec('php snapshot.php ...');
```

Нужно использовать:

```
exec('/usr/bin/php ' . __DIR__ . '/snapshot.php ...');
```

Привёл команду к такому виду и всё заработало!